# How to use FormControl result into interface instance?

Tags: typescript, angular-forms

I have the form in `FormGroup` instance and after submit I should set filled values into the object created by the interface scheme. But when I trying directly do this I stuck with error:

> ERROR in
>   src/app/modules/objects/object-form/object-form-components/object-information/object-information.component.ts(97,9):
>   error TS2322: Type '{ title: any; type_id: any; basises: any;
>   problems: any; material_id: any; ' is not
>   assignable to type 'ObjectFormComponent'.   Object literal may only
>   specify known properties, and 'title' does not exist in type
>   'ObjectFormComponent'.

```
const controls = this.informationForm.controls;
export interface ObjectCreateRequest {
  title: string;
  type_id: string;
  problems: string[];
  material_id: string;
}

const request: ObjectCreateRequest = {
  title: controls.title.value,
  type_id: controls.type.value.id,
  problems: controls.problems.value.map(item => item.id),
  material_id: (controls.material.value ? controls.material.value.id : null)
};
```

Into form all controls with `any` types and this invalid for the interface.

How I can do this?

Comment: Can you share more code? This part looks valid to me. `any` type can be assigned to anything without TS error. Maybe your interface contains some other required fields that you are not setting?

Comment: @Daniil Andreyevich Baunov update question

Comment: Also post the exact and complete error.

Comment: @JB Nizet updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error seems pretty clear, if you read through your error message. Specifically, `'title' does not exist in type 'ObjectFormComponent'`. Note that the error isn't describing the code you posted -- take a look at the filename and line number in your error to track down the line in question.

You have an object somewhere that defines 5 properties: `title`, `type_id`, `basises`, `problems`, and `material_id`. You used your types to tell TypeScript to expect an object of type `ObjectFormComponent` somewhere, but gave it that object instead. The problem is, your object has a field called `title`, which doesn't exist on `ObjectFormComponent`'s definition.

Does that make sense?

Comment: yes defiantly, I can't post directly code by strong security rules reason in my project, but you're post help me. Thank you.